# How could I pass IDs in before insert trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id, before-trigger, after-trigger

I need ID from records from custom objects
When I try before insert, I can't pass IDs (because newMap is null) and when I try after insert I also have an error "record is read-only"
I can do this with before update but is there a way to do this while inserting new records?

Comment: Like @Keith mentioned you can use a fake ID or index of the list for your task. Before Insert, wont have an ID as it has not yet saved in the database, but as you have mentioned you facing an error "record is read-only" are you trying to update the same record with some logic? If so you can formulate the logic in before insert and values would be updated. May be I misunderstood your question... you can tell us more what you are trying to achieve... that will give us an idea, what mroe can be done.

Comment: I want to assign ID from Case to lookup in a custom object in trigger - we have a requirement to do this both in before insert and in before update

Answer (score 2):

You can use the position in the list (the index) as an alternative to identify the records where you need to write logic related to each record.

But if you actually need the `Id` value to e.g. relate some other record to the records in your trigger, you will have to move to the `after insert` phase where the `Id` has been allocated and the records are in the database.

(If you are calling into a large body of pre-existing code that does require an `Id` but only for in-memory logic, you can allocate fake unique ones yourself. Generally safest to use the correct key prefix e.g. '006' from a describe call as part of making a syntactically valid fake Id so e.g. `getSObjectType()` works as expected.)